# Should I handle 'onTouchEvent' in a new thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, touch-event, viewgroup

I am trying to create **a custom ViewGroup** extending RelativeLayout.

It's going to be a complex one and **involves animating several child views simultaneously**.
Should I create a new thread to handle this callback?

I have found [this answer which suggests that for a long task a new thread must be created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466582/973425) but I'm still not certain "how long" the task must be.

I don't have much experience with customizing ViewGroups, maybe I'm **overestimating the computation requirements?**

Comment: I'm not sure how complex the calculation is, but even you can do the complex operations in a separate thread, you still need to do the UI related work in UI thread only.

Comment: You are right, most of the operations will still need to be on the UI thread. Maybe I should focus on optimization only after there's some visible performance issue.
I was trying to find whether some best practice already exists in these matters.